# SendMessage WM_COPYDATA between two processes

Tags: c++, string, process, sleep, sendmessage

I have to pass a string from one process to another, so I send `WM_COPYDATA` message with the relevant information. The receiver process waits by a `while` loop and sleeps for 500ms until the message received.

I don't know why it doesn't work. The sender process stops on `SendMessage`, because the receiver process doesn't get the message. When the loop on the receiver ends because the timeout, and the receiver process ends too, then the `SendMessage` of the sender ends and it can continue running.

Here is the relevant code. The sender process:

```
COPYDATASTRUCT cp;
memset(&cp, 0, sizeof(COPYDATASTRUCT));
cp.cbData = 128;
cp.lpData = messageStr;
cp.dwData = 45382;
::SendMessage(receiverHWND, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)&cp);
```

The receiver process:

```
// Define which function runs when a message WM_COPYDATA is sent
CopyDataHandler = onCopyData;

void onCopyData(COPYDATASTRUCT *cp)
{
    if (cp->lpData == NULL)
        return;

    if (cp->dwData == 45382) // means a message from the sender
    {
        strcpy(WinprocMessage, cp->lpData); 
        return;
    }
}

BOOL OnCopyData(HWND hWnd, HWND hwndFrom, PCOPYDATASTRUCT pcds)
{
    if(CopyDataHandler != NULL)
        CopyDataHandler(pcds);

    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        HANDLE_MSG (hWnd, WM_COPYDATA, OnCopyData);
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

**(Pay attention** that there are two functions: onCopyData and OnCopyData)

Now the code of the loop:

```
    _num attempts = procTimeout * 2;
    while ((attempts-- > 0) && (WinprocMessage[0] == '\0'))
        Sleep(500);
```

So, why doesn't it work? is `Sleep` function blocks other processes to `SendMessage`?

In addition, this code works fine with another sender process. (The other one is huge and I don't know it all, can't guess where the difference exists) Maybe the sender process have to `RegisterWindowMessage` somehow?

Comment: Well, sure it does.  Sleep() turns your process catatonic, it cannot *also* receive a message.  Which requires pumping the message loop, GetMessage + DispatchMessage.   Your while-loop doesn't, you probably don't have a message loop at all when you write code like this.  So can't work, use a named pipe instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. But I can't understand why when I run another sender process it works very fine! I also saw that in the call stack the sleep-loop went down, and the functions of the processing message are the higher functions.

Comment: It cannot possibly "work fine," a sleeping process is not pumping a message loop and therefore cannot receive a message. Hard to guess about code that we cannot see. Is there a compelling reason why you need to sleep and cannot just solve the problem the correct way?

Comment: @HansPassant I also don't understand why between two `Sleep`s the message isn't got

Comment: It sounds like you are relying on magic and hope a message will teleport into the WinprocMessage variable.  That magic simply does not exist, retrieving a message requires calling the GetMessage() function.  As long as you are calling Sleep() and *not* call GetMessage() you will never receive a message.  Calling Sleep() on the UI thread of a program is wrong 99.9% of the time.  The remaining 0.1% is reserved for the special kind of programming done in a game, inside a game loop.  Albeit that it uses PeekMessage().  This is covered well by Petzold btw, required reading.